# Android Exoplayer: getAudioComponent is null

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I am streaming audio with exoplayer and I want to have a button to mute and unmute the audio.

I am using these dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.10.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.10.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.10.5'
```

Player init code:

```
private void initializePlayer() {
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context);
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        playerView.setControllerHideOnTouch(false);
        playerView.setControllerShowTimeoutMs(0);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(mediaUrl);

        MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);

        player.addListener(playbackStateListener);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
        player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
        player.prepare(mediaSource, false, false);

    }
```

buildMediaSource:

```
private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, "exoplayer-codelab");
        return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(uri);
    }
```

this is how I am trying to mute and unmute:

```
    float currentAudioLevel = player.getAudioComponent().getVolume();
            mute.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                    if(!muteAudio) {
                        Objects.requireNonNull(player.getAudioComponent()).setVolume(0);
                        mute.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.ic_volume_off));
                        muteAudio = true;
                    }else{
                        Objects.requireNonNull(player.getAudioComponent()).setVolume(currentAudioLevel);
                        mute.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.ic_volume_on));
                        muteAudio = false;
                    }
            });
```

the getAudioComponent throws a null pointer exception:

```
 Attempt to invoke interface method 
   'com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player$AudioComponent 
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player.getAudioComponent()' on a null object reference
```

The audio is streaming properly and all the controls are working but I am not able to get or set the volume.

Comment: Impossible to say with the given code. Maybe `player.getAudioComponent()` is called before `initializePlayer()`. `buildMediaSource` is irrelevant here.

Comment: ok Ill look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use `player.setVolume(0.0f);`

I will recommend get the current volume first and then mute it. When you will unmute you can give user same volume.

```
float currentvolume;
currentvolume = player.getVolume();
player.setVolume(0.0f);
```